# Histogram plot with descriptive statistics on the plot

Tags: plotting, histograms

I am wondering in Mathematica

Can we generate histogram plot with descriptive statistics, such as mean, median, and skewness, attached to the plot ?

For example, we may place all the statistics to the right of the plot

Here is what I have done. First I created the function:

```
descriptivestatistics[
  data_] := {{"Mean", "Median", "Stdv.", "Skewness", 
    "Kurtosis"}, {Mean[data], Median[data], StandardDeviation[data], 
    Skewness[data], Kurtosis[data]}} // TableForm
```

Then, I placed them on the same list as follows:

`{Histogram[data,"PDF",Automatic],descriptivestatistics[data]}`,

but I think there is better way to do it.

Also, I want to export to be a report e.g., .doc or .pdf

Can any one give me suggestions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica's symbolic graphics architecture gives you a lot of flexibility to construct composite graphics. A simple way could be:

```
d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
descriptivestatistics[data_] := {{"Mean", "Median", "Stdv.", "Skewness", 
   "Kurtosis"}, {Mean[data], Median[data], 
   StandardDeviation[data], Skewness[data], Kurtosis[data]}} // 
 Transpose // Grid // Panel;
GraphicsGrid[{{Histogram@d, descriptivestatistics@d}}]
```

[image]

The documentation on `Export` will explain how you can export to various formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  How do you move the box on the right to get close to the histogram plot?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, with

```
d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
descriptivestatistics[data_] := {Mean[data], Median[data], 
  StandardDeviation[data], Skewness[data], Kurtosis[data]}
```

we construct labels & legend

```
hdr = {"Mean", "Median", "Std. Dev.", "Skewn.", "Kurt"};
tds = ToString@PaddedForm[#, {5, 2}] & /@ descriptivestatistics[d];
ltxt = StringJoin[hdr[[#]], ": ", tds[[#]]] & /@ Range[5];
lgd = Text[Style[ltxt[[#]], Bold], {-3, 25 - 1.4 #}, {-1, 0}] & /@ 
   Range[5];
```

We can use this as

```
Histogram[d, 10,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Band", "Count"},
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 2}, {Automatic, 2}},
 Epilog -> lgd
 ]
```

[image]